# What would cause a disk read error in Int 13h?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I've been writing a test program in NASM for a function that uses `int 13h` to read sectors off the booted disk except every time I run the assembled program with *sudo qemu-system-i386 load_disk.bin* it gives me this output:

> *disk read error! disk read error!* disk read error!* disk read error!* disk read error!*

which is expected if the carry flag (CF) is set. I've been looking for answers to this for days and tried lots of different solutions (jumping to `ES:BX` after `jc test`, saving boot drive in `DL`...) but nothing seems to work.
Here is my program:

```
[bits 16]                       ;real mode 
[org 0x7c00] 

mov [DISK], dl                  ;save boot drive value 

xor ax, ax                      ;setting up stack 
cli 
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, 0x7c00 
sti 

mov di, 5       `               ;counter for number of tries 
read_disk:                      
mov ah, 0x00                    ;resetting disk 
int 0x13 
mov bx, 0x9000                  ;data buffer 
mov es, bx 
mov bx ,0x0000                   
mov ah, 0x02                    ; function number 2 of int 13h 
mov al, 0x05                    ; read 5 sectors 
mov ch, 0x00                    ; cylinder 0 
mov cl, 0x02                    ; sector 2 (1 is boot sector)   
mov dh, 0x00                    ; head 1 
mov dl, [DISK]                  ; give dl value 
int 0x13                        ; call interrupt 
jc disk_error                    ;if carry flag is set 
jmp 9000h:0000h                
mov bx, [0x9000+512]            ;print bytes as if they were strings 
call print_string 

print_string:                   ; print_string function 
push bx                         
push ax 
loop_one: 
mov ah, 0x0e 
mov al, [bx] 
int 0x10 
cmp al, 0 
je end 
inc bx 
jmp loop_one 
end: 
pop ax 
pop bx 
ret 

disk_error:                    
cmp di, 0                        ; if number of tries=0 jump to loop   
je loop            
push bx                          ;print out the error message      
mov bx, MSG 
call print_string 
pop bx 
dec di                           ;decrementing di 
jmp read_disk 

loop: 
jmp $ 

MSG: 
db 'disk read error!', 0 

DISK: 
db 0 

times 510-($-$$) db 0           ; boot sector padding and BIOS trigger 
dw 0xaa55 
times 256 dw 'D'                ; sectors supposed to be read
```

Thank you for considering this question. I've really been at this for a while now.

Comment: How big is your image file that is created? You attempt to read 5 sectors plus the first 512 byte bootsector so you'll need at least a disk image that is 6*512 = 3072 bytes. On some emulators if you read beyond the edge of the disk image it will error out. Just a guess here. You really should set _DS_ to zero as well since you are using `org 0x7c00` as it isn't guaranteed that _DS_ will be set to zero. So at the top do an `xor ax,ax` `mov ds, ax` before you save the disk number, Change `times 256 dw 'D'` to `times 5*256 dw 'D'` whcih should give you an imae of 3072 bytes.

Comment: After `INT 13h, 2` the disk status is in `AH` - that value may provide a diagnostic clue - after all that is what it is for!  You should at lest output that in your error message.  http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_13-1.html

Comment: good tips from @MichaelPetch.Also, what is the return code in AH and number of read sectors in AL ?

Comment: it is impossible to make sense of this tangled spaghetti.  You should learn to use `call` instead of `jmp` where appropriate.

Comment: I thought my monitor was dirty, but it turns out that between the `mov di, 5` instruction and the comment to its right there is a stray backtick.  So, does this code actually assemble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem when I ran your code in Qemu, until I reduced the sector load count to 1 (from the 5 you had):

```
mov al, 0x01                    ; read 1 sector
```

Since your image only has one additional sector, and the emulator treats the image as the entire disk, you can't read any more than the one sector. With this change, your code "works" (doesn't print the error message).

Comment: Reducing to 1 or increasing the disk image to pad out to 3072 should suffice. Was why my comment under the answer suggested `times 5*256 dw 'D'` . But the number of sectors being read exceeding the disk image is the real reason for his problems. I am the upvote.

Comment: I'm not getting the error message anymore, seems to work thank you both.